# Swift - Creating a hashable tuple-like struct

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to create a hashable tuple-like object which can hold any type of object for use as a key in a dictionary. I use the structure in two places, once to hold 2 Ints, and once to hold a double and the previously mentioned 2 Int struct.

My current implementation cheats a little bit. I created a struct `Suple` which holds two ints, and is hashable, and then another struct `Duple` which holds a double and a suple, and is hashable. This *works*, but I figure there must be a better, cleaner way to implement this. After searching and messing around with generics I can't seem to get it to work, so any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** My code actually looks practically identical to Anton's EXCEPT for the  after the `==` in the declaration of equality. I didn't realize this was needed, and after adding that, it now works!

Comment: A look at what you've already done would be helpful - so I suggest you to post what you've done so far

Comment: Please post your code such that we could look at your implementation of Duple and Suple and suggest you further on this ? It is difficult to know from the description what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
struct Duplet<A: Hashable, B: Hashable>: Hashable {
    let one: A
    let two: B

    var hashValue: Int {
        return one.hashValue ^ two.hashValue
    }

    init(_ one: A, _ two: B) {
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
    }
}

func ==<A, B> (lhs: Duplet<A, B>, rhs: Duplet<A, B>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.one == rhs.one && lhs.two == rhs.two
}

let a = Duplet<Int, Int>(4, 2)

a.one
a.two
a.hashValue

let b = Duplet<Double, Double>(1.0, 2.0)

b.one
b.two
b.hashValue

let c = Duplet<Int, Double>(4, 5.0)

c.one
c.two
c.hashValue
```

Comment: Yes! My code actually looks practically identical to this, EXCEPT for the `<A,B>` after the `==` and this proved to be the difference. I didn't realize you needed that, but after adding that, it now works.